# Excel - VBA : set the standard format for all the cells of my Sheet once and for all

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a very annoying problem with excel : I have some VBA macros whose purpose is to fill in some other cells with some contents. My problem is that excel keeps changing the format of some cell ! Thanks but I didn't ask for this, everytime it tries to help me, it just makes things worse.
And when I right click on the cell to set the standard format and then try my macro again... it goes back to excel changes !

Here is an example of the problem I am experiencing :
[image]

Another example would be the number of decimals in a number : if my macro is copying/pasting a number with 11 decimals, excel is just gonna keep 7 !! So annoying!

Comment: Convert the Splits into string using cstr function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could copy your values only by passing them through a string variable e.g.

```
dim s as string
s = cstr(myrange.value)
mysecondrange.value = s
```

If your problem persists there's an issue in another part of you code.

The other issue maybe the new cell formatted to general and in this case excel will always assume it knows better changing the format to suite. Depending on your objective you may need to set the format yourself using the same VBA code e.g.

```
 mysecondrange.numberformat = "@" 'to text 
 'or
 mysecondrange.numberformat = myrange.numberformat 'to other cells format
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to keep your base data separate from your formatted data. First create base data sheets where you don't care about the formmatting. Then create your presentation sheets with formulas that pick up the data from the base-data sheets, and lock those presentation sheets completely. Even Excel cannot reformat a fully locked sheet.

Answer (score 0):

are you using **Paste** or **PasteSpecial**.

The former is the equivalent of `PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` which includes formats.

Maybe your code could use `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` or `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I am just using this kind of expression : "sMain.Range("A29").Value = Range(rowMax).Offset(0, -8).Value" An equal sign between two cell's content.

Comment: perhaps you could modify the **Style** of the worksheet to include the numberformat that you want?